# How to get a specific listview's column datas with REST API and ajax javascript?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, rest, sharepoint-rest-api

I want to be able to get the value in Column A of the selected document. I only want one column datas. And I can use Rest api and javascript.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use rest api as `/_api/web/Lists/getByTitle('<List Name>')/items?$select=<column Internal Name>` to get all the value in this column

Comment: So , if i want to get column' specific row? For example i want only data that i clicked.For example if i click second document and i only want to get PullThisData2 value. How can i do this ?